# Plot data around a circle ParaView

Tags: paraview

I have some data on the surface of a circle and I want to plot it on the circle, similar to the attached images (like a pressure map around airfoil). Does anyone know how I can do it in ParaView?

Thanks a lot

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use WarpByVector on a 3D circle with correctly positioned vector.